# Curious problem with generic web handler in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**UPDATE**

I am experimenting with some code in an ASP.NET Web Forms project and it isn't working as expected.

I have a simple web handler in ASP.NET that accepts a querystring and then calls a public method on a class to update a value.  Here's the *updated* code:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Test" %>

using System;
using CareAboutAir;
using System.Web;

public class Test : IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext ctx ) {
        try {
            var data = (string)ctx.Request.QueryString["p_type"];
            if ( data.ToLower ( ) == "fp" )
                SiteTrafficDB.AddView ( DateTime.Today, out _, out _ );
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            ctx.Response.Write ( "Hi!" );
        }
        catch {
            ctx.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            ctx.Response.Write ( "Hi!" );
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This code (as displayed above) does nothing.  I get no syntax highlighting or Intellisense, and it gets ignored when my web page calls it.  I get no errors in the browser console either.

My goal is to have web handlers that can go in their own folder rather than having to live in the root.  I have another version of this file (without the declaration at the top) that executes just fine so long as it is in the root folder of the web application, but if I put it anywhere else it is ignored and doesn't execute (I don't think it even gets compiled at runtime).

Any help?

Comment: Do you an .ashx file that goes with this handler? Or is it registered in web.config?

Comment: This is the code from the code-behind of the .ashx file. which only contains the class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

In `App_Code` folder and on some other special folders the asp.net is not allow to run pages and handlers.

[Shared Code Folders in ASP.NET Web Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/t990ks23(v=vs.100))

In other folders you must been able to run it - if not you must type here the error that you get - or just check it by your self - if not run you must have an error.

Also check the declaration on top of the page that is correct and not conflict with other classes. Must be like...

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Demo.Test" %>
```

Also I notice that when I create a handler from visual studio I do not have `namespace` on it.

Comment: I updated the code and my narrative of the issue.  Can you take another look please?  Thx!

Comment: @SRiverNet I have make some extra test - I do not see any error if you use other directories - when its not run I get actually an error message - what I suggest you is to try to remove the `catch {` to see possible errors - also see the EventViewer what error do you get when you run it. If its not runs - you must have an error on event viewer

Comment: I put a breakpoint on "try", and as long as I leave the webhandler in the root, the breakpoint gets hit.  The moment I put the file in a different folder, it doesn't.  It's as though the compiler never sees it when it rebuilds the app on execution.

Comment: @SRiverNet Forget the debugger for a moment - if you just run it what you get ?

Comment: @SRiverNet Put this line inside `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` and see if its starts the debugger when you run it - call it

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, click on your generic handler in Solution Explorer, then press F4 for "Properties".  Make sure your **build action** is "compile", not just "content".